# How to create a response with attributes in XML nodes using Apache2::REST?

Tags: xml, perl, rest

I am using the Perl [`Apache2::REST`](https://metacpan.org/module/Apache2%3a%3aREST) and the standard way of returning data is to issue `$resp->data()` and assign a value. I have something like this

```
my $text = {
    'tag1' => 4,
    'tag2' => 5,
    'tag3' => 6,
};

$resp->data()->{'text'} = {map { $_ => [$text ->{$_}] } keys %$text};
```

which gives me a response like this

```
<response message="" status="200">
  <data>
    <tag1>4</tag1>
    <tag2>5</tag2>
    <tag3>6</tag3>
  </data>
</response>
```

I would like to get to know how i create a response with an attribute in XML node `tag1` and can create tags of the same type on the same level?

Desired output is

```
<response message="" status="200">
  <data>
    <tag1 id="abcd"> 4 </tag1>
    <tag1>
      <tag3 id="xyz"> 6 </tag3>
    </tag1>
  </data>
</response>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this is to use the perl module `XML::Simple` with `ForceArray => 1`

```
$xml = '<tag1 a="' . '4' . '"b="4">';
$xml .= '<tag3 id="' . '3' . '">'; 
$xml .= '<tag2>' . '5' . '</tag2>';
$xml .= '</tag3>';
$xml .= '</tag1>';

my $tree = $simple->XMLin($xml, ForceArray => 1, KeyAttr => [ ]);
$resp->data()->{'xml'} = $tree;
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this will work, but it will produce a bit different output

```
my $text2->{tag1} = [4,{tag3 => 6}];
$resp->data()->{'text'} = $text2;
```

regards,

EDIT:

```
my $text2->{tag1} = [4,['val',{tag3 => 6}]];
```

Comment: +1 almost what i want, i get <text><tag1>4</tag1><tag1 tag3="6"/> . if you find me a way to get the last tag1 with a closing tag too and some innerValue i will accept your answer

Answer (score 3):

The module uses XML::Simple with no options but `RootName`. Knowing that, we know the following data structure will produce the output you want.

```
my $data = {
   'tag1' => [
      {
         id => 'abcd',
         content => '4',
      },
      {
         'tag3' => [
            {
               id => 'xyz',
               content => '6',
            },
         ],
      },
   ],
};
```

Test:

```
use XML::Simple qw( XMLout );
print XMLout($data , RootName => 'data');
```

Output:

```
<data>
  <tag1 id="abcd">4</tag1>
  <tag1>
    <tag3 id="xyz">6</tag3>
  </tag1>
</data>
```

(It will provide the `response` element.)